# Python modules and exit (beginner tier)

Tags: python, module

So, I'm having this problem, I'll try to explain:

```
#file1.py
    def main()
     if 1 != a:
       print "error"
       exit(1)
     else:
       print "sucess"
```

So I imported this "file1.py" in "file2.py"

```
#file2.py

    import file1
    control=2
    try:
      while True:
        if control == "2":
          main("2")
          print "something"
    except:
      print "error"
```

So, for some reason this "exit(1)" in the "python1" is exiting my code in "python2" after I call main("2") and the "print 'something'" is not being parsed.

Comment: how are these two files linked? Also `control=2` makes `control`  an `int` you are checking if control is equal to a string `"2"`

Comment: "file2" is basically a watchdog, it has a infinite loop and some conditions, when the conditions are satisfied, the "file2" will call "file1" through the 'main("2")' function. The problem is that the exits in "file1" are breaking the loop in "file2".

Comment: But that's what exit does. What exactly are you hoping to do?

Comment: You're calling `main("2")` in `file2.py`, but you defined `main` as taking no arguments in `file1.py`. Also, you're just calling it as `main`; if you did `import file1`, that can't possibly work, unless you've defined a function with the same name in `file2`… in which case whatever you defined in `file1` doesn't matter, because you aren't calling it.

Comment: I want to call the main() and exit from the main() when that "if" in "file1" is satisfied, but I want to keep the "file2" running after that.
Abarnert, that's right, but this error was only made in my example :D In my original code it's correct.

Comment: As a side note, it makes your code a whole lot easier to read if you follow consistent indentation. Start at column 0, not column 4; indent by 4 spaces always, not sometimes 2 and sometimes 1; etc. See [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a complete style guide.

Comment: @user3927607: When you `exit`, you've exited the whole program. Unless you wanted to start `file1.main` as a child process (which I'm pretty sure is not what you want), you shouldn't be calling `exit`. As hlt's answer (which I'd upvote, except I ran out of upvotes for the day…) explains, I think you want `return` there.

Comment: BINGO! The problem is that I wasn't using return... That's working now, thank you for your help, guys; specially @abarnert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never get to the `print "something"`. `control` is set to `2` (an integer), but you compare it with `"2"`, which is a string, you should use `control == 2` instead.

Once that is fixed, the call to `main("2")` can even happen. This will throw an error, because your `main` function takes no arguments. Also, `a` is not defined in `main` (if you want `a` to be the function argument, use `def main(a):` instead of `def main():`

Then, if `a` were equal to `1` (again, an integer, not a string), it would call `exit`, which **exits the entire python script**, including what you have in `file2.py`, unless you happened to catch `SystemExit`, which you **should not do**. That's what `exit` is for. Try `return` to exit a single function instead.